# Create List<> from runtime type

Tags: c#

I am looking to create a List, where the type of T is several unrelated classes (with the same constructor arguments) that I know through reflection.

```
    DataBase = new ArrayList();
    foreach (Type T in Types)
    {
        DataBase.Add(new List<T>);
    }
```

Unfortunately, Visual Studio says that 'The type or namespace T could not be found'.
Is there some way I can implement this, or cast a List to type T?
Thanks,
Peter

Comment: Use the `dynamic` keyword, perhaps? Assuming the right version of .NET...

Comment: don't use `ArrayList`, worst case just use `List<object>` if you must

Comment: @BrokenGlass, I will probably do that, but it is not the ArrayList that is the issue, it is the creation of the List with runtime Type.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can use reflection:

```
List<object> database = new List<object>();
foreach (Type t in Types)
{
   var listType = typeof(List<>).MakeGenericType(t);
   database.Add(Activator.CreateInstance(listType));
}
```

Comment: That works.  But creating the List object is just a small part of problem.  He'll also have to add elements to it.  And worse, much worse, read them.  That code won't know the element type either.  An ORM is indicated here, given the word "database".

Comment: That works to create the object, but it returns an object. I got that far, but I'm having trouble casting that object as a List<T>. I could of course use "as List<T>" if I knew T, but since that's not defined until runtime I'm not sure how to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

You're confusing types and the System.Type class for [Generic Type Parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0zk36dx2%28v=vs.80%29.aspx), here is the code to implement it the way you want:

```
var lt = typeof(List<>);
foreach (Type T in Types)
{
    var l = Activator.CreateInstance(lt.MakeGenericType(T));
    DataBase.Add(l);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could... use `List<object>` (if you know that your type is a reference type, or boxing is acceptable); or [create a List via reflection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms379564%28v=VS.80%29.aspx#csharp_generics_topic9).